# C# Devolver un valor genérico <T> cuando la clase genérica es un enumerado (System.Enum)

Tags: c#, genericos

Tengo un método que deberá crear una variable del mismo tipo que el Genérico pasado y devolver esta variable cargada con un determinado valor en función de un parámetro pasado, el problema que tengo es que cuando quiero devolver el tipo T me da error y al definir la variable también.

tipos posibles: a asignar y retornar

```
public enum IdDoc_FactMntBruto {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")] Item1,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3,
}


public enum IdDoc_TckMntBruto {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3,
}
```

Metodo en dónde debería implementar y devolver el Genérico.

```
public static T enumIndicadorMontosBrutos_TO_IdDoc_FactMntBruto <T>(enumIndicadorMontosBrutos indicadorMontosBrutos) 
    {
                    
        var indicador = (tiene que ser del mismo tipo T)

        switch (indicadorMontosBrutos)
        {
            case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.IVAIncluido:
                indicador = T.Item1;
                break;
            case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.IMEBAyAdicionalesIncluido:
                indicador = T.Item2;
                break;
            case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.ContribuyentesIvaMinimoMonotributoMonotributoMIDES:
                indicador = T.Item3;
                break;
            case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.NoIncluyenIva:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return indicador;
    }
```

Al asignar T.Valor tengo error ya que T no me está tomando los valores que están en el enum del tipo que pasé en T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para devolver primero debes instanciarlo de esta manera genérica:

Así se hace en una clase genérica, cuando T es un Class.

`T indicador = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), null);`

En el caso de un enum se debe considerar:

```
if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("La clase T debe ser un enum");
```

(Prefiero usar el ***T*** en vez del ***var***, se ve como de la vieja escuela y la gente te cree más intelectual. /Homero con las gafas de intelectual/)

Activator, lo encuentras de esta forma:

```
using System.Activator;
```

Cuando el constructor es vacio.

Si quieres devolver null, debes usar esto:

`return default;`

Sin embargo recomiendo manejar este concepto : Covarianza y contravarianza en genéricos.

Referencia en español:

[https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#:~:text=Covarianza%20y%20contravarianza%20son%20t%C3%A9rminos,espec%C3%ADfico](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#:%7E:text=Covarianza%20y%20contravarianza%20son%20t%C3%A9rminos,espec%C3%ADfico))%20que%20el%20indicado%20originalmente.

La razón es que no se conoce que propieades puede contener T, amenos que  T herede de : un TParent.

Por ejemplo:

```
 public static T enumIndicadorMontosBrutos_TO_IdDoc_FactMntBruto
 <T>(enumIndicadorMontosBrutos indicadorMontosBrutos) where T : TParent
```

En tu caso vendrá mucho mejor esto:

```
 public static T enumIndicadorMontosBrutos_TO_IdDoc_FactMntBruto
 <T>(enumIndicadorMontosBrutos indicadorMontosBrutos) where T : System.Enum
```

Esto aplica para cualquier otro tipo de clases.

**where T : TParent**

Donde TParent sea algo asó como:

```
public class TParent  
{
    public static string Item1;
    public static string Item2;    
    public static string Item3; 
}
```

Sin embargo encuentro un posible error;

```
switch (indicadorMontosBrutos)
{
    case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.IVAIncluido:
        indicador = T.Item1;
        break;
    case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.IMEBAyAdicionalesIncluido:
        indicador = T.Item2;
        break;
    case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.ContribuyentesIvaMinimoMonotributoMonotributoMIDES:
        indicador = T.Item3;
        break;
    case enumIndicadorMontosBrutos.NoIncluyenIva:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Sugerencia 1:

```
default:
 return default;// ( Para devolver un registro nulo)
```

Sugerencia 2 ( Cuando no es un enum ):

```
 indicador = T.Item2;
```

Esto es confuso pues a menos que T estrictamente pertenezca a una familia de clases que tengan la propiedad estática Item2
REF_2

esto lanzará un error. Creo que la idea es algo así como :

```
 indicador = indicadorMontosBrutos[2];
```

Finalmente el plus es este:

Si deseas iterar sobre todos los valores numerados:

```
foreach (T item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
{
 acción
}
```